# Finding volumes with double integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I got some troubles with this problem:

*A swimming pool is circular with $20\,ft$ diameter. The depth is constant along east-west lines and increases linearly from $4\,ft$ at the south end to $9\,ft$ at the north end. Find the volume of water in the pool.*

What I've tried is to find the function which describes the depth of the pool, but I'm not sure how to describe this function. Besides, I suppose that my integration domain is the circle $x^2+y^2 = 100$.

Thanks for all your comments!!

Comment: -1 this is ridiculous. It takes a few seconds to get the answer, without going near an integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is a lot easier to perform this calculation with simple geometry (having the average height being $\frac{13}{2}$), performing it with double integrals isn't that hard either.

Focusing on the depth of the pool, as your question describes (and using some of André Nicolas's answer), the depth (height or z value) of the pool can be modeled by $D(x,y) = \frac{5}{20}y + \frac{13}{2}$.

Therefore we have the function $z = f(x, y) = D(x,y) = \frac{5}{20}y + \frac{13}{2}$ to model the depth/height/bottom of the pool.

If you want to use double integration to find the volume of the pool; we need to integrate with a domain; which you have described:

$$
V = \iint_D D(x,y) \,dx \,dy.
$$

Where $D = \left\{ x^2 + y ^ 2 \le 100 \right\}$; not being the easiest to work with; we can translate this function to work in the [Polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). Mapping the function with $f(x,y) \rightarrow f(\rho \cos \phi,\rho \sin \phi ).$

In doing this, we can see that the translated domain will be $T = \left\{ 0 \le \rho \le 10,\, 0 \le \phi \le 2\pi \right\}$. We then just need to re-do the integration:

$$
\begin{align}
V &= \iint_T D(\rho \cos \phi, \rho \sin \phi)\rho \, d\rho \, d\phi \\
 &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{10}\left(\frac{5}{20}\rho\sin\phi + \frac{13}{2}\right)\rho \, d\rho \, d\phi
\end{align}
$$

Solving this double integral gives $650\pi$. And when we use the most simple approach of $V = \pi r^2 h$ with the height being the average of $\frac{13}{2}$, we also get $650\pi$.

**Another Way**
You can also use the [Cylindrical coordinates system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) with the mapping of $f(x,y, z) \rightarrow f(\rho \cos \phi,\,\rho \sin \phi,\,z).$ This this, the translated domain will be $T = \{ 0 \le \rho \le 10,\, 0 \le \phi \le 2\pi,\,4 \le z \le 9 \}$. To solve this you need to use a tripple integral in the following fashion:

$$
V = \int_{4}^{9}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{10}z\,d\rho\,d\phi\,dz
$$

Answer (score 0):

Choose axes so the top of the pool is bounded by the circle $x^2+y^2=100$.

The depth at $y=-10$ is $4$, and the depth at $y=10$ is $9$. Let the depth at $y$ be $D(y)$. Then $D(y)=py+q$ for some numbers $p$ and $q$. We are told that $-10p+q=4$ and $10p+q=9$. So $p=\frac{5}{20}$ and $q=\frac{13}{2}$.

Now we are ready to integrate. If we take a little $dx\times dy$ rectangle on top, the volume below it is approximately $(py+q)\,dx\,dy$. "Add up," (integrate) over the disk.

But one-variable techniques will also work. The cross-sectional area at level $y$ is equal to $(py+q)(2x)$, which is $(py+q)(2\sqrt{100-y^2})$. Integrate from $y=-10$ to $y=10$.

**Remarks:** $1.$ There is much less to the calculation than meets the eye. The function $(py)(2\sqrt{100-y^2})$ is odd, so the integral over an interval symmetric about $y=0$ is $0$. And the remaining integral is closely connected to a familiar area.

$2.$ We can also find the answer purely geometrically. There is symmetry, and the average depth is $\frac{13}{2}$.